# How do I make sure I receive the whole message if it doesn't fit in the buffer in TCP?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I recently started to work with TCP in C#. I'm now at the point where I want the client to receive the data sent by the server.

I know that there is no guarantee for the client to receive all data at once. If the size of the data sent is bigger than the buffer's size at the client's side, then the data will be sent in parts. So my question is: how can I store all my received data in a byte array, and then convert it to the actual message when all is received?

I've set the buffer size to 1, so I can see what happens when all sent data doesn't fit in the buffer. Here are my methods in which I call `stream.BeginRead()` in Client.cs:

```
// Deliberately setting the buffer size to 1, to simulate what happens when the message doesn't fit in the buffer.
int bufferSize = 1;
byte[] receiveBuffer;

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    client.EndConnect(result);

    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");

    stream = client.GetStream();

    // At this point, the client is connected, and we're expecting a message: "Welcome!"
    receiveBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), stream);
}

private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int bytesLength = stream.EndRead(result);

    // Should be "Welcome!". But of course it's "W", because the bufferSize is 1.
    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesLength);

    Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", receivedMessage);

    // Reset the buffer and begin reading a new message, which will be "e".
    // However, I want the whole message ("Welcome!") in one byte array.
    receiveBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, ReadCallback, null);
}
```

This is the output when sending the message "Welcome!":

```
Connected to server.
Received message: W
Received message: e
Received message: l
Received message: c
Received message: o
Received message: m
Received message: e
Received message: !
```

Should I temporary store the data until the whole message has arrived, and then convert that to a string?

Follow up question: What if 2 messages are sent closely after each other, for example `Welcome!` and then `What's your name`? How do I distinguish the two messages then?

Comment: _"Should I temporary store..."_. Yes. You may also prefix the string/packet with its length (if you want to). _"What if 2 messages..."_. You can't. You need a _protocol_ for that. You could use a delimiter (like - for example - mandatory newline after each _message_). If you prefix with the packet size then you might also use it to distinguish between packets. Usually no need to reinvent the wheel, there are MANY ready-to-use protocols and libraries to do exactly this. Hint: you're sending/receiving _messages_...

Comment: Just for clarification - Even if the client's buffer is larger that the data, there is still no guarantee that all of the data will be received at once. It really depends on how the network buffers the data - not necessarily the buffer defined in code. MSDN states NetworkStream.Read - "This method reads as much data as is available into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read." You always want to check the # of bytes actually read.

Comment: Also in case it helps, the topic you are looking into is called 'TCP Message Framing'. This page has some basic ideas: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I temporary store the data until the whole message has arrived, and then convert that to a string?

Yes, exactly.

> Follow up question: What if 2 messages are sent closely after each other, for example Welcome! and then What's your name? How do I distinguish the two messages then?

The general approach is to send the length of the message before the message itself. That way the receiving end will know when it has received a complete package.

Answer (score 0):

As 500 - Internal Server Error already pointed out, you use a buffer for it. Here is some Code example:
Receiving:

```
while (true) //you should use a bool variable here to stop this on disconnect.
                {
                    byte[] bytes;

                    bytes = ReadNBytes(ns, 4);
                    //read out the length field we know is there, because the server always sends it.
                    int msgLenth = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                    bytes = ReadNBytes(ns, msgLenth);
                    //working with the buffer...
                    if (bytes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //do stuff here. bytes contains your complete message.
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) { Log(e.Message); }                            
                    }
                }


public static byte[] ReadNBytes(NetworkStream stream, int n)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[n];
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;

            int chunk;
            while (bytesRead < n)
            {
                chunk = stream.Read(buffer, (int)bytesRead, buffer.Length - (int)bytesRead);
                if (chunk == 0)
                {
                    // error out
                    Log("Unexpected disconnect");
                    stream.Close();
                }
                bytesRead += chunk;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Log(e.Message); }

        return buffer;
    }
```

To send stuff use something linke this:

```
public static void SendObject(NetworkStream ns, byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] lengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
        ns.Write(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
        ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

I hope that helped!